# Unsupported Media Type when using Jersey and Jackson from uberjar

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest, maven

I am currently facing a problem with Jersey and Jackson where I can't find a solution for: When I am trying to get an POJO serialized from JSON as a POST-Parameter in an Jersey-Endpoint, it returns an error if I call it from an uberjar. If I use the same wget-call after I started the main-method from eclipse, everything works fine and I get the expected answers. I've searched for other people having problems when using jersey and post-parameter application types, like [Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: POST not reaching REST if JSON, but it does if XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if) and [JAX-RS: How to automatically serialize a collection when returning a Response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771830/jax-rs-how-to-automatically-serialize-a-collection-when-returning-a-response-ob), but the main errors where that they didn't specify headers in the call or use wrong @Consumes-tags, which I do not. According to my research no one had similiar problems that the call worked when the server was started from eclipse, but did not work when the server was started externally.

The class starting the server is the following:

```
public class ServerStarter {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8282/test/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("starter");
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
        System.out.println(String.format("Drücke Enter um Server zu beenden.", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

And the Endpoint looks like this:

```
@Path("testme")
public class Endpoint {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String testMe(Parameters ep) {
        return ep.toString();
    }
}
```

And the Parameters-class, which should be the POJO, looks like this:

```
public class Parameters {
    private int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

If I do mvn clean package assembly:single, start the server and then call `wget localhost:8282/test/testme --post-data='{"x": 10 }' --header="Content-Type: application/json"`, it returns `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

The dependencies in the pom.xml are the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am out of clues, as far as I thought, the call from eclipse should be similar to the call in the uberjar.

Comment: Maybe the syntax has changed since JAX-RS 1.0, but shouldn't that be an array of strings in the @Consumes value, e.g. `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})` ?

Comment: I'm faing a similar problem with Jetty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971384/jetty-jersey-jackson-different-behavior-in-eclipse-success-vs-command-lin

Comment: i had the same problem and i was able to fix it by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971384/jetty-jersey-jackson-different-behavior-in-eclipse-success-vs-command-lin/40843828#40843828

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but unfortunately, this was a packaging-problem and not a jersey-problem, so activating the jackson-feature manually wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was to be caused by services (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service_Provider), which are provided by the jars. While eclipse combines them correctly, the uberjar-plugins makes them overwrite each other. One possible solution is to use the maven-assembly-plugin instead, using the following assembly-descriptor:

```
<assembly>
    <id>production</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>    
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>classes</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Afterwards one can start the application with `java -cp lib/:classes/ MainClass`.

Comment: FYI you can use `Maven Shade plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin`  because it provides class relocating feature, to avoid same class name conflict in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

David analysis is correct. I just want to add an alternative solution. You could use Maven Shade plugin with `ServicesResourceTransformer` for e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <transformers>
            <!-- To ensure the original META-INF/services definitions are respected -->
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>id.web.michsan.hellotransfer.Application</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```